# gnome-keyring-daemon fills syslog and auth.log

Tags: server, crash, docker, gnome-keyring

I have an intermittent problem with my ubuntu machine running 20.04, after around a week of continuous uptime the machine will start to fill both the syslog and auth.log with the following message.

Jun 06 16:26:53 gnome-keyring-daemon[2127]: couldn't accept new control request: Too many open files

A reboot of the machine will make it stop filling the log files but i can't get to the bottom of what is causing this issue. Occasionally I've caught it late and its filled the full hard drive and i've have to truncate the log file to clear space. I could alter the log rotate but i'd rather get to the bottom of the issue. I've found a few threads with similar issues but not a fix. Does anyone have any ideas of what might be causing this?

The machine is mainly used for running a bunch of common docker applications under a single docker-compose

many thanks

Comment: it probably is not gnome-keyring-daemon but a software asking for permission and not getting it and not asking you for it. Do you have anything special running that would need permissions? Like VNC or SSH?

Comment: i have SSH and VNC.

Comment: It is is vnc: stop vnc, kill gnome-keyring-daemon, restart vnc and then try to connect. It should one time ask for the keyring password. Unlock it and it should stop the log filling up. Exact the same happend here and that was the answer: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/ubuntu-63/gnome-keyring-fills-my-auth-log-4175678088/#post6142906

Comment: I’ve tried that before and the problem will still happen in around a week of uptime. I’ve purged the vnc install for now to see if that is the cause though. Thanks and will update again if it does or doesn’t work

Comment: @robsimpson  Did you ever get to the bottom of that ?  I just encountered a similar issue with the auth.log and sys.log filling up really fast (GB's every 10 min or so).  I was also running Docker with NGINX, PostGres, etc, although the server hadn't been rebooted itself for awhile.  It might be related to the NGINX workers, etc., but I'll have to dig into it a bit.  Was getting the exact same error.

Comment: @robsimpson I should say that the server host hadn't been rebooted for probably months, and one of the containers uses NGINX with FPM.  It might possibly be related to 'worker_processes auto;' and worker_connections 1024; and possibly some of the keepalive settings.  It might be mostly an NGINX config issue ?